# SQLSTATE[HY000]

Tags: sql, laravel, phpmyadmin, migration

Need help to solve a SQL error in laravel
I need to migrate the database tables but it displays an error "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" in the client table because the foreign key table (equipment table) is under the client table and in the same time the equipment table needs modalite table and client table before . How to solve that ??
Thanks for your help I am open for any advice !

solving the problem

Comment: Please attach what your table looks like and what you are trying to do...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.